# How to add mention adapter on $ character in Android socialview along with @?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-studio-2.2, mention

We want to enable tagging feature based on $ character and @ character  in Android socialview, with 2 different adapter. Any idea how can we achieve this. Please refer to this link for Android Socialview

https://github.com/hendraanggrian/socialview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [here](https://github.com/hendraanggrian/socialview/blob/main/socialview/src/com/hendraanggrian/appcompat/internal/SocialViewHelper.java). Line no. 177 just changing the regex from # to $ should work but there is no direct way of setting it while using their library. You will have to include the source code directly inside your app and make the change.

Edit:

As [@Darkman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10534012/darkman) suggested change the code at 183 for mentions. `@(\\w+)` to `[@$](\\w+)` will do the work.

Comment: You're almost right. Not at line 177 but 183 instead. 177 for hashtag and the other one for mention tag. And yes changing `"@(\\w+)"` to `"[@$](\\w+)"` should do the trick.

Comment: @Darkman Thanks, We also need to make change at line no. 50 in this following file. it worked for me

https://github.com/hendraanggrian/socialview/blob/main/socialview-commons/src/com/hendraanggrian/appcompat/widget/SocialAutoCompleteTextView.java